# Updating properties in a component as soon as changed are made in the same or other component through services

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am working on a simple project , a music player.

I have the songs in an array in **service.ts** through which component **liked-songs** get all the songs to display to the user, and these two components are children of **home-component** which receives the song to be played and has play pause button etc.

My concern is that I am having a like button on the player (near play pause button) in home component and when that like button is clicked for the song , That song's liked is set to true and the like button turns red for that song. and also the song is displayed on **liked-songs component** by filtering through liked property of songs.

But the problem I am having is that the song isnt added to the list immediately on clicking the like button and neither does it turn red. These take place only after I click and return from another component or click on another song and then return to the liked song(only then it starts showing red colored like button)

Is there anyway to update these list in real time. I think it can be done using **observables** but I am not getting it on how to apply it for this..

Below is the code for reference.

**service.ts**

```
  getSongs() {
    return this.songs
  }


  songs: Song[] = [{
    url: "./assets/song1.mp3",
    name: "Song1",
    singer: "Song1 singer",
    img: "./assets/song1.jpg",
    liked: false,
    inplaylist: false
  }]

likeclicked(songurl: string) {
    var song_liked = this.songs.filter(element => element.url == songurl)[0]
    song_liked.liked = !song_liked.liked
  }
```

**liked-component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.likedsongs=this._allsongs.getSongs().filter(element=>element.liked==true);
  }
```

**home-component**

```
liked(songurl: string) {
    this._allsongs.likeclicked(songurl)
  }
```

All the functionalities are working fine(song liked changes to true from false or vice versa when like button is clicked) But it doesnt update the array in real time.
Any recommendation would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you messing around with the change detection ? Also if you are using some form of `*ngFor` in the template, are you also using `trackBy` functions? If possible can you add some simple stackblitz example.

Comment: I dont think I am messing with change detection and yes I am using ngfor but not using trackBy.

Comment: @ХристиянХристов and also its pretty obvious why it does not update the array as soon as a song is liked because the likedsongs array gets songs on ngOnInit

Comment: Ok, I guess then you already found your answer :D.  Here is a solution with a small update on the template side : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jdcoyd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @ХристиянХристов I didnt get any solution but urs one actully pretty much relates to what I wanted. The only difference is that the liked songs list that u are showing is a different component for me and also the place where I like a song is a different component than all the song list. Can u pls help me with that